# Owl Carousel issue with Bootstrap tabs

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, owl-carousel

Im almost done with creating a neat user profile page where users can watch their profile. Im working with the Bootstrap framework integrated in Wordpress. Im using [Bootstrap's Tabs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs) in order to get a lot of info on one but and keep it clear for the user. 
I have two main tabs, called "AWF I" and "AWF II", inside those tabs I have info about the fund, and a Owl Carousel to display pictures
[image: The AWF I tab is active here]
As you can see the carousel works great, but when I activate tab "AWF II" I get this:
[image: The AWF II tab is active here]
As you can see, the pictures / carousel itself are super small, and I have no idea how to overcome this, the carousel should display like the one in the "AWF I" tab.
Here is a clue that might give you guys some idea on why this is happening: when I rightclick and inspect the element in Google Chrome, the carousel pops to the correct size like it should be:
[image: The correct display should be this]
**but** when I switch back to "AWF I" after, that carousel displays the small images, so basically, inspecting with Google Chrome makes them switch role.

Any clue on this? please let me know if you need more info! Thanks!

**UPDATE 01**

Here is the code I use to call the carousel:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#owl-awf1-properties,#owl-awf2-properties").owlCarousel({
    pagination: true,
    loop: true,
    dots: false,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplayTimeout:2000,
    autoplayHoverPause:true,
    margin:10,
    responsiveClass:true,
    responsive:{
        0:  {
            items:2
        },
        450:{
            items:3
        },
        767:{
            items:4
        },
        991:{
            items:5
        },
        1199:{
            items:5
        }
    }
});

});
```

Comment: You wouldn't use Owl Carousel in something that doesn't get its height on page load, it requires an actual resize to work or it works on page load, if it's inside something that is not loaded when the page loads (tab-pane or panel group content) then it won't work. Owl Carousel is responsive but it's not fluid, it's responsive through the use of jQuery but not through the use of media queries.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Epmwx/ -- make a fiddle and see if you can duplicate it so that you can get help.

Comment: Thanks! at least we now know it's because of the loading of the page. Is there some jQuery we can use and bind to the tab button thats forces the carousel to work? I updated the Fiddle and placed images inside and it works correctly, if we can't figure it out without the fiddle I will try my best to replicate it, but it's gonna be hard because I use loops and stuff. Thanks for so far!

Comment: Are you lazy loading? That might be why it doesn't work.

Comment: Im not using lazyload, I added the js I use to call the carousel to my original post

Comment: Try this: http://jsbin.com/vasuji/1/edit?js - it works with Owl1 it may work with Owl2, as far as I can see but that may change.

Comment: Thank you for helping me out. Unfortunately, this does not work, I copied the code in my theme.js file and the same problem still exists.. Do you need more info from my side? Thanks!!

Comment: @Christina, I have the site live, but the section of the site is password protected because it contains confidential information about a user. I created a test account for you to login and view the carousel. Please go to this url: http://www.mijnawf.nl/mijn-awf/ and login. If you sent me a mail to boriskamp1990@gmail.com I will sent you the login info Thanks!

Comment: SO is about helping all folks with the same problem and so you need to create an isolated version of this on JsBin or Fiddle and then let the community help you.

Answer (score 2):

**@Jason Anello**, A mod at www.teamtreehouse.com solved this issue by suggesting to switch from the Owl Carousel 2 to the Older but more stable Owl Carousel 1! I changed my css and js files from version 2 to version 1 and now the carousels load like they should! Thanks Jason!!

Thanks Christina for trying to help as well!

Comment: Did you find some other kind of solution? Cause switching to version 1 is not possible in my case.